# Unable to build gradle-7.0.0.pom

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Android Studio unable to build gradle any sample project, I tried using proxy also accepted server certificate at the time of start it prompts me to accept, but still fails to build any project. Also tried auto-proxy configuration. Need help. Attached screenshot
screenshot : 1 -> exception occured on my hostname [image]
screenshot : 2 -> server certificate of android studio [image]

Comment: try creating sample project on different wifi or 4G connection. If the problem still persists you need to reset android studio and internet connection settings to default, do not use any proxies or VPN

Comment: Yes I tried with different wifi, problem still persists. I also tried reset android studio and my internet settings. :-(